# Add more more than one attribute to a Javacript

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a second attribute to this javascript to change the color of the href to white.

```
 $("#linkImagen").attr('href', "https://meet.jit.si/" + text);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#linkImagen').click(function () {

            $(".chatboxtextarea").val("Quiero tener una videollamada contigo. Hacer click aquí: https://meet.jit.si/" + text);
            $("#enviarMensaje").click();
        })
    })
```

Comment: 'href' has no color. It's an HTML attribute, it's code. What are you trying to turn white?

Comment: Looks like a homework problem. lol.  try `attr(` with color or style as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Either style or color like this...

```js
const text = 'lorem ipsum...';
 $("#linkImagen")
    .attr('href', "https://meet.jit.si/" + text)
    .attr('color', "#FFF")
    .attr('style', "color: #FFF")
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="linkImagen">FOOOOO</a>
```